# How to configure address in JAX-WS CXF Client using JNDI lookup

Tags: spring, web-services, jax-ws, cxf, spring-el

I am looking up my JNDI value of endpoint (properties file is not an option) on server like this

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="MyEndpoint" jndi-name="endpoint.url" />
```

I would like to use the above looked up value in the place of address.

```
<jaxws:client id="helloClient"
       serviceClass="demo.spring.HelloWorld"
       address="http://localhost:9002/HelloWorld" />
```

I tried  `address="${MyEndpoint}"`. Did n't work. Looks like I have to use another bean, which uses jndi value and use its method to return as string  i.e. `address="#{MyBean.geyMyEndpoint()}"`. Doesn't look clean that way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use Spring Expression Language to get the behavior you want, without using another bean.  The following works for me in Tomcat 7:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="MyEndpoint" jndi-name="java:comp/env/MyEndpoint" />

<jaxws:client id="helloClient"
       serviceClass="demo.spring.HelloWorld"
       address="#{MyEndpoint}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. It seems address="#{MyEndpoint}" started working after I updated by imported XSDs to Spring v3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Also on another note from Spring 3.1 - Spring has unified property management. so instead of the above solution you can do this

```
<jaxws:client id="helloClient"  serviceClass="demo.spring.HelloWorld"  address="${endpoint.url}" />
```

endpoint.url could be any property(system, environment etc) and it will automatically resolve the property. so no need to do separate JNDI lookup and your code looks clean.